# Azure Webjob/function Retry count

Tags: azure, queue, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

In a webjob with a trigger on a blob, I want to manage my retry count, because I need to do something at the last retry count, if I do just a try-catch I will lose my retry mechanism, and I can't wait for message to go to poison, because in the blob triggers all the messages of all the jobs listening to blobs goes to the same queue and I can't know where the poison messages come until I read all the queue !

so any idea (if it is possible) to get this retry count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the maximum number of retries via the `maxDequeueCount` setting in the "queues" config. That affects blob functions is because behind the scenes a control queue is used for dispatching blobs to your functions.

And the below is the sample code to configure queue, in there you will be able to configure the `maxDequeueCount` and the default number should be 5. Here is the doc link:[Queue storage trigger configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#queue-storage-trigger-configuration).

```
    static void Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage(a => {
            a.BatchSize = 8;
            a.NewBatchThreshold = 4;
            a.MaxDequeueCount = 4;
            a.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        });
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but what I need is on my function code, to try 4 times with error
and on the last one go a different logic to go in an if or something, but I think what I'm asking for is impossible...

Comment: @Maroine Abdellah, actually I think you could use [Graceful Shutdown](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown) and listen to `CancellationToken` you can pass to you triggered function and judge the property `IsCancellationRequired` value , then you could handle the WebJob would shut down. Here is the [sample code](https://github.com/mathewc/samples/tree/master/WebJobSamples/ContinuousJobGracefulShutdown) about CancellationToken.

Comment: @Maroine Abdellah,any process now? Did you still have other problem?

Comment: thank you for the answer, the answer was accepted, I didn't have time to try it but your answer should work.